# Is it possible to define template literal type with `keyof`?

Tags: typescript

I have defined a form schema type for e.g.

```
type FormSchema = { username: string; settings: { theme: string; language: string } }
```

Now I want to define the Form Input type as follows

```
type FormInput = { id: keyof FormSchema | `${keyof FormSchema}.${string}` }
```

I cannot set the template literal part it gives an error:

`Type 'symbol' is not assignable to type 'string'`

EDIT:

I had a syntax error in my question sorry for that I tried to simplify my question, here is my actual code that has the problem:

```
export type FormSection<
  FormSchema = { [key: string]: any | { [key: string]: any } }
> = {
  id: string;
  elements: FormElementGeneric<
    keyof FormSchema | `${keyof FormSchema}.${string}`,
    FormInputTypes,
    FormInputTypesProps
  >[];
};
```

[image]

Typescript version 5.2.2

Comment: [I cannot reproduce](https://tsplay.dev/WyQ3dW).  Please make sure that your code is a [mre] others can use to demonstrate the issue for themselves.

Comment: Syntax Error: `type FormInput = { id: keyof FormSchema | \`${keyof FormSchema}.${string}\` }`

Comment: Sorry for that, I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know with TS version you're running, but this works with 4.1 or later.

Here is how you define the `FormInput` type:

```
type FormSchema = { username: string; settings: { theme: string; language: string } }
type FormInput = `${keyof FormSchema & string}` | `${`${keyof FormSchema & string}`}.${string}`;
```

In this code, the `FormInput` type includes the top-level keys of `FormSchema` (like "username" or "settings") and also concatenated keys (like "settings.theme" or "settings.language"). These concatenated keys are created using the template literal types feature in TypeScript.

You can use this type like this:

```
const input1: FormInput = "username"; // Valid
const input2: FormInput = "settings.theme"; // Valid
const input3: FormInput = "invalid"; // Invalid, as "invalid" is not a valid key
```

Each of these input variables is assigned a string that matches one of the keys in FormSchema or a concatenated string of keys.

P.S: If the string doesn't match any of these possibilities, TypeScript will throw an error, enforcing the type safety of your code

The [Doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html)

Comment: Thanks! I solved it by adding `& string` only to the template literal part.